# How to skip a commented section ( /* ....*/ when we grep for a word in a file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How to skip the commented section in a file when we grep for a particular phrase.

Example : I want to search for kali.

```
object Host "linux" {
import "windows"
address = "linux"
groups = ["linux"]
}

/* -comment section starts
object Host "kali" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = [linux ]
}
*/  -  comment section ends

object Host "linux" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = ["windows" ]
}
```

The output I expected is "empty" it would not result "object Host "kali" {"

Comment: What is the tool/type/language of the source file ?

Comment: Seems to be `icinga`

Comment: You need a proper parser, but if you are willing to require that `/*` and `*/` be on different lines and that none of the comments are interleaved, you can simply pre-filter with something like `sed '\@/\*@,\@\*/@d' input`

Comment: @WalterA  Thanks, It works but one more question. If the string exists outside a commented section, I want to know the file name where the string exists not the full line where the string exists in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you should use the icinga2's API via [CLI](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/11-cli-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using **awk** instead of **grep**

`awk -v pattern="kali" '/\/\*/{f=1;next}/\*\//{f=0;next}!f&&$0~pattern' inputfile`

Comment: Thanks, It works but one more question.

If the string exists outside a commented section, I want to know the file name where the string exists not the full line where the string exists in a file.

Comment: this works as case sensitive, i want this as not case sensitive, Kindly help on this
@Yoda

Answer (score 0):

```
cpp -P file | grep kali
```

can expand some things you don't want, but seees to work nice for OP.
Additional question in comment: How to show the filename
When you want to perform this for a set of files and want to know in which file you have un uncommented hit, you can do something like

```
for f in *; do
   tmpfile="/tmp/kali.${f}"
   cpp -P "${f}" > "${tmpfile}"
   grep -l kali "${tmpfile}" | sed 's#/tmp/kali.##'
   rm -r "${tmpfile}"
done
```

or without tmpfile

```
for f in *; do
   cpp -P "${f}" | grep -q kali && echo "${f}"
done
```

Comment: Is * represents location?  @Walter A

Is there any way to achieve this without any loop statement ??

Comment: `*` represents a mask for the files you wat to address, it might be `somedir/*.cfg`. You could make use of `find` or `xargs` for constructing an oneliner without `for`, but in fact you will be doing the same work.